# How to supress nullpointer warning in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullable

I have a parent class with final variable that can be null. It is annotated with Nullable.
The parent class is extended by multiple classes, some of them have this variable as Nullable but some of them as NonNull. Now when I am using the variable in the subclass I see the warning about NullPointerException. It seems redundant to enclose the variable with if/null when I know it cannot be null (in the subclass constructor it is annotated as NonNull). How to make it clear for anyone reading the code that it cannot be null and make it clear to IDE as well ? My take is to preceed the usage with assert property != null. But I wonder if that is a good way.

```
class A {

  @Nullable
  final String propertyA;

  public A (@Nullable String propertyA) {
      this.propertyA = propertyA;
  }
}

  class B extends A {

  public B (@NotNull String propertyA) {
      super(propertyA);
  }

  public void doSomething() {
      //Here is the warning from IntelliJ but I know it is not null.
      propertyA.equals(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do much about this. How about making a new `propertyA` in the subclass? If you can't, please show some code illustrating why.

Comment: You can suppress the inspection for the whole class by annotating the class with `@SuppressWarnings({"DataFlowIssue"})`. Is that a "good" way in your opinion?

Comment: IntelliJ also accepts a `//noinspection DataFlowIssue` line just above your check. But IMHO an assertion feels easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The value you're getting by calling "propertyA" in your doSomething method is the property in the class A, which is annotated with @Nullable.

If you really want to avoid this, you can use a getter, and override it in the B class with a @NotNull annotaiton, but you would just duplicate your code.

And be aware that the @NotNull annotation doesn't prevent a value from being nullable, it is only used for code warnings in IJ! You should add a check in your B constructor to validate that the value is really not null.